# Windows Azure Virtual Machine, Server 2012, Can Not Activate 0xC004F074

Tags: windows, azure

I have just created a Windows VM in Azure, running the Windows Server 2012, December 2012 image from the provided gallery, however, now that it is launched, I cannot get Windows to Activate it fails with the error code 0xC004F074.

I've followed a couple of forum threads including [Windows Server 2012 Datacenter Not Activating - Windows Azure](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/WAVirtualMachinesforWindows/thread/f29d5fe7-4f0f-433d-8333-1d336f68a4db)

However, this does not work. Another forum thread said this problem was being experienced and corrected itself after Windows updates had been installed, this is not the case for me.

Anybody got any ideas about how to fix this issue? Or, if I don't activate will I be able to carry using the install with no issues?

Thanks very much,

Martyn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common **activation bug** in Windows Azure and **Microsoft** are aware of the problem and currently **working on a fix** for it.

The issue was discussed in this post (**point 7**) on the **Windows Azure Technical Support Team Blog**:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2013/02/08/windows-azure-virtual-machines-common-issues/

*Please note that activation status does not impact the services running on the server. Not activating will generate persistent notifications reminding you to activate the server. Services and remote administration are not affected.*

Answer (score 1):

First of all even when you are seeing this issue, your VM will still work fine and will not impact the services running on your server. However I do understand that it not activating the VM will generate continuous notifications for you to activate the server even when services and remote administration are not affected. Windows Azure team does know about this issue with a small percentage of VM however if you would want to notify your issue as well you can contact them direct at iaasforum@microsoft.com

If you want to try to fix this issue by yourself, there are few users who played with SLMGR application to disable the selected activation server and  then used proper activation server as below:

```
slmgr -skms kms.core.windows.net <correct_port_number>
```

This following forum discussion has more details on how to use SLMGR application inside the Azure VM to try to fix this issue so you can try as well and report your results.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforWindows/thread/f29d5fe7-4f0f-433d-8333-1d336f68a4db/

Comment: Thank you for assistance, could you tell me why the machine not being Windows Activated will not cause it to lock up after 30 days in the same way that a stand alone machine would? That is what I am concerned about...  Thanks very much.